# Проблема с компилированием Typescript

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, typescript, webstorm

В общем работаю в PHPstorm  компилю через `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true  
  },
  "files": [
    "Main.ts"
  ]
}
```

Файл собирает но пишет следующее

```
"use strict";
var index_1 = require("../node_modules/typedi/src/index");
var CarFactory_1 = require("./CarFactory");
var Counter_1 = require("./Counter");
var carFactory = index_1.Container.get(CarFactory_1.CarFactory);
carFactory.create();
var counter = index_1.Container.get(Counter_1.Counter);
counter.increase();
counter.increase();
counter.increase();
console.log(counter.getCount());
//# sourceMappingURL=Main.js.map
```

Браузкр естественно ругается

> require is not defined

Как быть?

Comment: В браузере нет `require`. Модули надо собирать чем-то вроде `webpack` или `browserify`

Comment: Спасибо все заработало